# Query regarding Transit Visa and Baggage Tag

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I have a query on below two itinerary:

Ticket # 1 on different PNR

Delhi-Amsterdam-Delhi

KL  872  17JAN DELAMS 0310   0715

KL  871 17MAY AMSDEL 1425  #0140

Ticket # 2 on different PNR

Amsterdam-Curacao-Amsterdam

KL  735  17JAN AMSCUR  1000   1450

KL  736  16MAY CURAM  1525  #0640

Passenger is Indian Passport Holder and believe that Transit visa not required.

Secondly passenger will proceed from Curacao to Port of Spain on Surinam Airways and take visa on arrival.

My question is as follows:

1. Do KLM will permit to board the aircraft at Delhi Airport as they will have two different PNR  ticket on KLM and one ticket on Surinam Airways.
2. Do they will face any challenge on their check in baggage, I mean can the baggage be tag till Curacao as both will be same carrier even though issued on separate PNR/ticket.

Answer (score 2):

> Do KLM will permit to board aircraft at Delhi Airport as they will
>   have two different PNR  ticket on KLM and one ticket on Surinam
>   Airways.

No.

For KLM, they are transporting you to Amsterdam, and you (the traveler) need to show proof that you are able to be landed there.

As far as KLM is concerned, you are not in transit.

> Do they will face any challenge on their check in baggage ...i mean
>   can the baggage be tag till Curacao as both will be same carrier even
>   though issued on separate PNR/ticket.

As you are only being checked in on one flight (DEL - AMS), your bags will only be checked through to AMS. You will have to collect your bags, and proceed to the KLM counters for your next flight - of course to do this, you will need to land (pass immigration) in AMS as the baggage collection is after immigration.

For the second segment (AMS - CUR) you will need to show at the check-in desk in Amsterdam  that you have the appropriate visas (or don't need a visa) to pass immigration in Curacao.

---

If your flight was DEL - CUR on KLM, then you would have no issues as they would check your bag directly through to CUR, print you two boarding passes DEL-AMS, AMS-CUR at Delhi, and you would be on your way.

The way the trip is setup, you have two separate journeys that are not linked together at all.

Comment: If OP shows his onward ticket to check-in staff at Delhi, they may be able to issue both boarding passes at Delhi itself and check baggage through to CUR as it is same airline. I have done so on Turkish and faced no problems. I believe there should be similar facility on KLM as well.